# Tail a log on a server I am ssh'ing to and display it dynamically on a web page

Tags: java, javascript, shell, ssh

Basically what I want to do is write a script that will allow me to ssh to a server and tail a log, then pass pack the file descriptor of that tail and display it dynamically on a webpage. I already have an idea how to dynamically update my webpage using jquery but can anyone tell me how to remotely tail a log?

Answer (score 2):

You can do `ssh host.com tail /var/log/some_file`. You will have to do this periodically or use -f and append it some where. Last, you should set up your ssh keys so you don't have to type passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I was wondering if there was a way we could do it without having to ssh every time we wanted to refresh the browser. P.S. sorry it has taken me so long to respond, my computer crashed yesterday.

Comment: jsch will be able to do this.

Comment: I don't think there is because if you think about the constrain. You have to get the latest tail to be able to process it. To do that you need to ssh. So you have two options. ssh everytime. OR keep an open ssh connections and cat to some local file. This is probably what you want. After maybe 30 min timeout, kill the ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jsch if you want full portability.
This example should get you started.
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java

EDIT: You should set up ssh-keys jsch. I assume this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the code of Jenkins/Hudson, they have this implemented rather neatly and it's open source.

Comment: I like their implementation, but don't really understand it. :(